# Drawing equilateral triangle in the middle

Tags: three.js

I want to draw a triangle in the middle of the scene so I pushed vertices like this and it worked:

```
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
```

My question is, if I reorder push methods, triangle is not being rendered and I don't understand why, for instance:

```
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
```

Why is that happening? I can't find anything in documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3D, each face has a normal attribute computed when you call `geometry.computeFaceNormals()` in three.js. If a face normal points toward the camera, the face will be drawn, otherwise it won't. How to decide which side of the face will be the front side ? It depends of the order of the vertices. If you look at a face and if the indices of its 3 vertices grow clockwise, you are watching the front side. Otherwise it is the backside. It is called the **winding order**.

I guess you did not change their indices in the face declaration, `new THREE.Face3(0,1,2)` but if you change the order of the vertices in their array, it is the same of course.

So actually you are now looking your face from the backside. You can see it by changing the camera's point of view (change the order and move the camera to the back in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a02bemz/1/) ).

If you don't want to worry about the winding order and be able to watch the faces from any point of view, three.js offers you that in the `material` parameters : just add

```
side:THREE.DoubleSide //default is THREE.FrontSide, there also is THREE.BackSide
```